# If a group satisfies $x^3=1$ for all $x$, is it necessarily abelian?

Tags: group-theory

I know that any group satisfying $x^2=1$ for all $x$ is abelian. Is the same true if $x^3=1$? I don't think it is, but I can't find a basic counterexample.

Comment: In short, no; the result does not hold for *any* $n$ other than $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: It is however true if there are no elements of order 3!

Comment: @Steve D: You mean, if $x^3=1$ for all $x$ and $G$ has no elements of order $3$? Well... it's a rather singular situation, don't you think? (-:

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: hahaha, it's funny that what I wrote is still, somehow, correct.  I was thinking of $(xy)^3=x^3y^3$.

Answer (score 19):

For any odd prime $p$, there is a nonabelian group $H_p$ of order $p^3$ and such that $x^p = 1$ for all $x \in H_p$: the [Heisenberg group modulo p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p).

**Added**: As Dylan Moreland points out, [this expository note of Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf) gives a very nice discussion of the groups of order $p^3$, including the Heisenberg groups $H_p$.

Comment: See also [this handout](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf) of Keith Conrad's.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read this stuff.