# To check given group is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If a group satisfies $x^3=1$ for all $x$, is it necessarily abelian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147642/if-a-group-satisfies-x3-1-for-all-x-is-it-necessarily-abelian)

I want to show that group $G$ is abelian (i.e. $ab=ba$) if $a^{3}=e, \forall a\in G.$
I am trying so much but i cant get this so please help me out!

Comment: I think this has been asked before. One second.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147642/if-a-group-satisfies-x3-1-for-all-x-is-it-necessarily-abelian). The result is not true. Are you leaving out some hypotheses?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $a^2=e$, or $a^3=a$?

Comment: Actully, $$a^{3}=a$$ $$\Rightarrow a^{2}a=e.a$$ $$\Rightarrow a^{2}=e.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have a hard time proving it, since the result is false.

Let $\mathbb{F}_3$ be the field with three elements, $0$, $1$, and $-1$ (with $1+1=-1$). Let $G$ be the group of all matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & c\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),$$
with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_3$.

Denote that element as $(a,b,c)$. Then
$$(a,b,c)(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = (a+\alpha, b+\beta, c+\gamma+\beta a).$$

Show the group is not abelian, but $x^3 = e$ for all $x$. This is known as the [Heisenberg group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) corresponding to $p=3$.

More generally, for every prime $p\gt 2$, the similar group satisfies $x^p=e$ for all $p$, but is not abelian. A presentation for the group is
$$\Bigl\langle a,b,c\,\Bigm|\, a^p = b^p = c^p = 1, ac=ca, bc=cb, ba=abc\Bigr\rangle.$$